# ASP Entity Framework Show data from another model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a table called TestAnswer and one called question

This is the Create Script created by Entity Framework.  I have added some viewbags

ViewBag.TestAnswerQuestion gives me values from the Question table as a select list.  I want to show them as normal text e.g. @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.QuestionText) in my razor view for TestAnswer

How can i get the questions to show in my TestAnswer create view

// GET: /TestAnswer/Create
        public ActionResult Create()

```
    {


        ViewBag.CurrentTestUser = User.Identity.Name;
        ViewBag.CurrentTestUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        **ViewBag.TestAnswerQuestion = new SelectList(db.Questions.Where(t => t.QuestionID == 2), "QuestionID", "QuestionText");**
        ViewBag.TestAnswerTestID = new SelectList(db.Tests, "TestID", "TestUser");
        return View();


    }
```

Comment: Are there multiple Answers to each Question in your entity model? You appear to be selecting one Question in the Where clause of you highlighted line of code - did you intent to select multiple Questions?

Comment: Just one question.  Each question has 4 answers stored in the same table.  In Test Answers only one answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to pass a Model back to your View when returning from your Controller action method.

If I understand you correctly, you want to return a Question entity to your TestAnswer/Create view, perhaps something like:

```
var model = db.Questions.Find(t.QuestionID);
...
return View(model);
```

Then you can reference the model from the View template:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.QuestionText)
```

If you want to show a select list of Answers to the Question, your Question entity could have a collection of Answer entities as a public property, then you can simply navigate from a Question to its Answers.

The best advise I can give you is to consider the Entities and their relationships carefully, and model them as POCO classes. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may want tot return a View Model, when is a transformation of you entity model to another form that is optimized for the View.

Comment: Thanks Saille.  What I have is a list of questions.  The Question table has QuestionText, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD.  I have a separate table called TestAnswer.  I have a join in the model between TestAnswer and Question.  The TestAnswer Stores the QuestionID.   My plan is to generate a random question as you show var model = db.Questions.Find(t.QuestionID);. I then want to display that in the Create TestAnswer View.  If I use the Test Answer View and say return View(model);  I get an error.  The EF automatic code shows return View() but when I add the model it fails